# How to set pragma from sqlite .net wrapper

Tags: .net, sqlite

Searching web I found info about declaring pragmas but I can't use it
For example an ordinal  `mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery` sql command with an sql statement "PRAGMA synchronous=OFF" or "exec PRAGMA synchronous=OFF" results in error.

How to set this pragma?...

Comment: `PRAGMA synchronous=OFF` from an `ExecuteNonQuery` should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: You are right. I used to expect, on return, an integer greater than 0 as result. But for the case the result shows rows affected which is indeed 0. So for this case result 0 does not indicate an error... It works.